# heroku+s3+paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

Guys,
I'm having a problem with s3...I'm trying to configure the s3 this way to work with the paperclip:

has_attached_file :photo,

```
:storage => :s3,

:bucket => 'gallerybucket',

:styles => { :small => ["150", :png], :large => ["500", :png], :very_large => ['750x500>', :png] },


:path => ":rails_root/public/images/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.png",


:url => "/images/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.png",


:default_url => "/images/sem_imagem.gif",

:s3_credentials => {
  :access_key_id => ENV['ac'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['sc']
}
```

but it always shows me this error. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Is there some configuration missing?

Comment: have you confirmed that ac and sc are stored as environment variables on heroku?

Comment: Now the app is runing in the heroku, but when I run it locally it gives me this error: AWS::S3::NoSuchKey in Public#gallery_detail

Showing /home/andrelima/workspace/cec/app/views/public/gallery_detail.html.erb where line #15 raised:

The specified key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an s3 account already go get one here:

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

You need to add this to your contact model:

app/models/contact.rb

```
  has_attached_file :picture, 
                     :styles => {:large => "275x450>"},
                     :storage => :s3, 
                     :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                     :path => "appname/:attachment/:style/:id.:extension"
```

Make sure you appname is your rails app name on heroku. And make sure you rename picture to whatever you have named your picture.

Then you need a config file in `config/s3.yml`.

```
development:
  bucket: bucked_name
  access_key_id: key
  secret_access_key: secret

production:
  bucket: bucked_name
  access_key_id: key
  secret_access_key: secret
```

Make sure you get the key and secret correct.

In your gem file make sure you have these gems install :

```
gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"
gem "paperclip"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you added the variables to you heroku account, but did you add them to your .bashrc file?

```
export ACCESS_KEY_ID='acckeyid'
export SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='secacckey'
```

Then in your code:

```
:s3_credentials => {
  :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
```

I have a [blog post](http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/keeping-credentials-out-of-your-code-with-environmental-vars/) I wrote that talks about this a little as well.

Comment: Man, I tried it, but it didn't work. I'm putting the s3 credentials in a separate file, s3.yml, this way: access_key_id = 'acckey'
secret_access_key = 'secacckey. I inserted this lines that you suggested in the bashrc file, but the same error is shown.

Comment: OK I edited my answer. I know you have those vars working on Heroku but I thought I would go with clearer names and uppercase it to make sure there is no confusion with any other variable. Hopefully it is a little more clear. Watch out for spaces between your variable and the assignment. Bash does not like that: VAR='value'